# Toggle timer between RUN and RESET JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to do a simple timer who can run from 25 to 0 and reset whenever we want to.

For this I've made a clickable div, and I want one click to start the timer and another one to reset it to 25 and stop the timer, is this possible ?
A toggable start/reset timer?

This is what I came up with so far :

HTML

```
<div id="result" onclick="playReset"><p id="output"></p> </div>
```

CSS

```
#result {
  background: pink;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 400px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
#result:hover {
 border: black solid;

}
#output{
  margin-left: 70px;
position: fixed;
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

And the most important the JS :

```
var duree=25;
var toggle = true;
function playReset () {


if(toggle == true) {
 var time = setInterval(function(){ 
  duree--;

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = duree;                   
                      }, 1000);

  toggle = false
}
else if (toggle == false) {
  clearInterval(time);
  duree = 25;
  toggle = true;
}

}
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = duree;
```

Thank's if someone can give me a hand, I have SO MUCH trouble understanding setInterval/timeout, clearInterval/timeout ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I simplified that code a little, where you can use the actual `time` variable to check whether it is running or not.

Stack snippet

```js
var duree = 2;
var time;
function playReset() {
  if (time) {
    clearInterval(time);
    time = null;
    duree = 25;
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = duree;
  } else {
    time = setInterval(function() {
      duree--;
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = duree;
      if (duree == 0) {
        clearInterval(time);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
}
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = duree;
```

```css
#result {
  background: pink;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: transparent solid;
}

#result:hover {
  border: black solid;
}

#output {
  margin-left: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="result" onclick="playReset();">
  <p id="output"></p>
</div>
```

---

When you later on have increased your skills, you likely want these stuff and their variable hidden from the global environment.

With closure one can do something like this, where only the function name is public.

Stack snippet

```js
(function (output,duree,time) {  //declared as static variables
  this.init_time = duree;
  this.playReset = function() { 
    if (time) {
      clearInterval(time);
      time = null;
      output.innerHTML = duree = init_time; // set init value
    } else {
      time = setInterval(function() {
        output.innerHTML = --duree;
        if (duree == 0) {
          clearInterval(time);
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
  }  
  window.playReset = this.playReset; //make it public
  output.innerHTML = duree; // set init value
  
})(document.getElementById('output'),25);  // pass in the output element and default time
```

```css
#result {
  background: pink;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: transparent solid;
}

#result:hover {
  border: black solid;
}

#output {
  margin-left: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="result" onclick="playReset();">
  <p id="output"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: gosh.. this is it ☻, I have some questions tho, when you do "if(time)" 
it mean "if (time == true)" right? 
Then you put it on null to make it false? And then it's true since it take the setInterval function ?
and at the beginning when you just declare "var time;" it's like saying "var time =true", ?

Comment: @Jukker `if(time)` will validate to false if the `time` is, in this case, null or undefined. The initial declaration `var time` will make it be undefined since no value were set. The `time = setInterval` will assign it an number ID, and numbers not being 0 will validate `true` for `if(time)`

Comment: Nice! You may wanna stop it at 0

Comment: Nice! I was playing around with this one too, I will post another answer. Kind of same solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is same solution, but with the event listener and I check the count to know if a reset is to be done. You can try this here:

https://jsfiddle.net/0bej5tyn/

html

```
<div id="timer">
  25
</div>
```

css

```
#timer{
  width:150px;
  height:100px;
  line-height:100px;
  border-radius:100px;
  border:5px solid #444;
  background:#555;
  font-size:50px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  font-family:arial;
}

#timer:hover{
  border:5px solid #333;
}
```

js

```
var timerButton = document.getElementById("timer");
var countStart = timerButton.innerHTML
var count = countStart;
var timer;

timerButton.addEventListener('click',function(){
    if (count == countStart){
    timer = setInterval(function(){
      count--;
      timerButton.innerHTML = count;
      if (count == 0){
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    },1000);
  }
    else{
      /* Reset here */
      clearInterval(timer);
      count = countStart;
      timerButton.innerHTML = count;
    }
});
```